# How to ignore or filter few records from excel file on node-red device before sending it to IoT core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, node-red

How to ignore or filter few records from excel file on node-red device before sending it to IoT core?

Can we do it with change node?

Comment: You need to supply a lot more context, including what you've tried and how it didn't work